# Apache htaccess rewrite slash followed by questionmark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a Laravel Lumen project and issue something strange. I created a restful API on some of the routes. If I call the API directly from my browser everything seems to work. However if I use an iPhone client application of a debugging interface an additional slash is added.

The API is currently located at:

http://.../public/index.php/api/fever?api&items

Whenever an iPhone application or debug tool is used the following location is requested:

http://.../public/index.php/api/fever/?api&items

This results in a 'page not found' error. Is is possible to use the apache htaccess rewrite rule to redirect all *api/fever/?* to *api/fever?*  ??

The htaccess file has to be located in the public folder, which is located under a sub folder under the main website.

Thanks in advance

**current htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this redirect rule at top of your site root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !.*/api/fever/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.*api/fever/\S*)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NC]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Almost.. It only removes the /public/

Comment: The htaccess has to be located in the public folder. This is a requirements by Laravel.

Comment: Thanks. We're almost getting there. The public folder is also within a sub directory of the main website. It is currently redirected to the public website within main website. Any solution for this?

Comment: You already have a rule adding `/` and now you want this rule to remove `/`?

Comment: Try my updated rules after clearing all browser cache.